# Solr Parallel SQL query support for deep paging

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there a way to create a SOLR sql query with cursorMark field can be part of the where clause and nextCursorMark as part of the resultset ?

I would imagine like this:

```
SELECT nextCursorMark, field1, ... fieldn limit 100 FROM collectionName WHERE cursorMark='something'
```

Answer (score 0):

For Solr Parallel SQL, you shouldn't need to worry about using cursors with deep paging. Parallel SQL will use the /export handler to handle large result sets.